# Coherent Information of Entanglement Breaking channels

Tags: hilbert-spaces, information-theory, quantum-information

The book by John Watrous, "The Theory of Quantum Information" is an exciting read for anyone wanting to research quantum information theory. The following question presumes some background covered in the book, which I will do my best to explain.

**Question:**
If $\mathcal{X}_0, \mathcal{X}_1, \mathcal{Y}_0, \mathcal{Y}_1$ are complex Euclidean spaces (Finite dimensional Hilbert spaces on complex field) and $\Phi_0 \in C(\mathcal{X}_0,\mathcal{Y}_0)$ $\Phi_1 \in C(\mathcal{X}_1,\mathcal{Y}_1)$ are two quantum channels, with $\Phi_0$ being entanglement breaking, then show that
\begin{equation}
I_C(\Phi_0\otimes\Phi_1) = I_C(\Phi_1).
\end{equation}

**Background:**
Here, the space of channels $C(\mathcal{X}_0, \mathcal{Y}_0)$ consists of linear, completely positive trace-preserving (CPTP) maps on $L(\mathcal{X}_0)$ (linear operators on $\mathcal{X}_0$) returning operators in $L(\mathcal{Y}_0)$. For any channel $\Phi$ and state $S$ (states are non-negative operators with unit trace), the coherent information $I_C(\Phi;S) = H(\Phi(S)) - H((\Phi\otimes I)(vec(\sqrt{S})vec(\sqrt{S})^\dagger))$ and $I_C(\Phi) = \max_S I_C(\Phi;S)$, where the maximum is taken with respect to all states.

A separable state is a state of the form $\sum_i p_i P_i\otimes Q_i$, where $P_i$ and $Q_i$ are states with $\sum_i p_i = 1$ with $p_i\ge 0$. States that do not have this kind of representation are called entangled. An entanglement breaking channel is one whose output state is always separable even if the input is entangled.

There is a theorem that may prove useful: The following are equivalent.

1. $\Phi$ is entanglement breaking (EB).
2. For any finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{Z}$, $\Phi\otimes I_\mathcal{Z}$ is separable where $I_\mathcal{Z}$ is the identity map in $\mathcal{Z}$.
3. There exist states $\rho_i$ and non-negative operators $M_i$ such that $\sum_{i}M_i = I$ (called a POVM) such that $\Phi(S) = \sum_i \rho_i Tr(SM_i)$.

I was able to show $I_C(\Phi_0 \otimes\Phi_1) \ge I_C(\Phi_0) + I_C(\Phi_1)$ for any two channels $\Phi_0$ and $\Phi_1$. The book does prove that $I_C(\Phi) \le 0$ for $\Phi$ EB.

I will be happy to offer any clarification if required. This problem has been bugging me for quite some time now and I cannot see a way through. This problem would interest students and Professors working in Quantum Information Theory.

**Update:** Based on a comment, this question has been ported to [QuantumComputing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12783/55).

Comment: just in case you didn't know, these types of questions are also very much on  topic on [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, I was not aware there was that SE. The problem solution, in my opinion, was likely to be more math-oriented, which is why I posted it here.

Comment: I have asked this question on quantum computing stack exchange. According to rules, should I delete this question or is it fine if I keep it active here as well?

Comment: it's up to you. Different sites have different policies for cross-posting. As far as quantumcomputing.SE goes it's fine. I don't know about math.SE. Regardless, if you decide not to delete this one (which is fine by me), it's good form to link the two questions, to avoid duplicating efforts

Comment: Ok. I will mention it in the body of the question. I will leave it to the moderators to take a call on it.